# Unable to start rabbitmq-server on debian 6 squeeze

Tags: debian, rabbitmq

I try to start rabbitmq using:

```
/etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server start
```

then I get

```
Starting rabbitmq-server: TIMEOUT - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_{log,err}
rabbitmq-server.
```

I checked startup_log and startup_err but they don't show anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does "don't show anything" mean? If they are literally empty then that is a sign that there is some sort of permissions problem. What is the last line in the startup_log file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good candidaes are:

- permissions of `/var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang-cookie` (**must be 0600 IIRC**)
- existance of an erlang cookie
- `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia` you can try to move the mnesia database away and restart the server (should be recreated automagically)

Otherwise:

Please show the the `startup_err` file (or rather relevant parts)

NOTE: The paths are from memory, could be wrong so take with a grain of salt...

Comment: I had the same problem in Wheezy, and the permissions on .erlang-cookie somehow got to be 0400. After resetting to 0600, it started just fine. Thanks!